# How to fix "Variables might not have been initialized"

Tags: jsp

It might be a stupid question, but really I can't see why it's not working. When I write this in my JSP, it says that the variables might not have been initialized. What confuses me is that I've tried to do the in Java with the input of a Scanner. What I'm trying to here is to see if the input (username & password) equals an account from http://javabog.dk:9901/brugeradmin?wsdl. 
The Java code for the database and interface work fine

```
<%

    // hvis brugernavn="Jacob" og adgangskode="hemli" logges der ind.
    // dette burde selvfølgelig hentes fra en database eller lign.
        URL url = new URL("http://javabog.dk:9901/brugeradmin?wsdl");
        QName qname = new QName("http://soap.transport.brugerautorisation/", "BrugeradminImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
        Brugeradmin ba = service.getPort(Brugeradmin.class);;


                String bn;
                String ak;
        Bruger b = ba.hentBruger(user, password); //variables user and password might not have been initialized

    bn = request.getParameter("brugernavn");
    ak = request.getParameter("adgangskode");
    if (bn.equals(user) && ak.equals(password))
    {
            //response.sendRedirect("Nykode.jsp");
        // sæt attributten "logget ind" i sessionen
    session.removeAttribute("logget ind");
        out.println("Velkommen");
    }
    else
    {
        // fjern attributten "logget ind" fra sessionen
        session.removeAttribute("logget ind");
        out.println("Forkert brugernavn eller adgangskode.<br>");
    }
%>
```

It's in danish, but what I want it to do is: if the username and password are correct it should remove "logget ind" and print "Velkommen".

I hope you can help me out of this :)

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I'm trying to :)

Comment: After doing it, it gives me `com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException: Client received SOAP Fault from server`